# Append text to all files in a directory using batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm a complete batch beginner..

I'm trying to simply add 'exit' to the last line of every text file in a folder.

I get that it's some combination of FOR and ECHO but I can't get it to work even after doing a lot of searching.

My current attempt;

```
FOR %%i IN (*.*) DO echo exit >> %cd% %%i
```

:(

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you explained why you think you “can't get it to work”; but I'm guessing you want:

```
FOR %%i IN (*.txt) DO ECHO exit>> %%i
```

Don't put a space after the text you want to `ECHO`. I don't know why you have `%cd%` in your redirection; that will try to send the text to your local directory, which makes no sense. If you're trying to send it to a file in a different directory you need to separate them with Window’s directory separator:

```
... ECHO whatever>> \other\directory\%%i
```

You don't need that with %cd%